# why following code is not taking all inputs?

Tags: c, input

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int a;
    float b;    
    char ch;
    
        scanf("%d%f%c",&a,&b,&ch);
        printf("%d %f %c",a,b,ch);
    return 0;
}
```

whenever I run above code

its takes only two inputs and terminates why is that?
I want to input :2,3.5,d.but its terminates after 3.5.

here is image of when I run the code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ef6CE.png

Comment: Update your question to demonstrate the "three" inputs you're providing from stdin.

Comment: `%c` is matching the newline character after `3.5`, so it is what is stored in `ch`. Add spaces in your `scanf` between the format specifiers, it will rectify the issue.

Comment: have you tried adding spaces in between the "%d%f%c", as far as I know scanf() needs the spaces in order to consumer the '\n' character.

Comment: @EugeneSh. thanks it worked ,yes after adding spaces it worked .can you please explain why is that happening ?

Comment: No, the `"%d"` conversion specifier consumes leading whitespace. (in fact all conversion specifiers except `"%[..]"`, `"%c"` and `"%n"` consume leading whitespace)

Comment: @YogeshSatyam The space in format string is matching any number of whitespaces (including newline) in the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is the fact that you do not have a whitespace between the "%f" and %c" conversion specifiers, and without it after the "%f" scanf() consumes the newline character as the given character.

this might help you https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html

As a matter of a fact, I placed a whitespace between the "%f" and "%c", and the following program seems to work on https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a;
    float b;    
    char ch;

    scanf("%d%f %c",&a,&b,&ch);
    printf("%d %f %c",a,b,ch);
    return 0;
}
```

Furthermore, if you print your data using parenthesis `'printf("(%d %f %c)",a,b,ch);` you will see the consuming of the newline character for yourself.

The output of the original program, without the whitespace between %f,
%c:

```
2
3.5
(2 3.500000 
)
```

The output of the edited program, with the whitespace between %f, %c:

```
2
3.5
x
(2 3.500000 x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Include spaces in [format](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) string. Otherwise any whitespace character (spaces, newline and tab characters) will be read into your variables. So, include a space before `%c` like this:

```
scanf("%d%f %c",&a,&b,&ch);
```